# Why isn't my widgets working?

Tags: django

I have form:

```
@parsleyfy
class Form_registration (ModelForm):
class Meta:
    parsley_extras = {
        'password': {
            'minlength': "5",
        },
        'password2': {
            'equalto': "password",
            'error-message': "Your passwords not equales",
        },
    }
    model = Users_data

parsley_namespace = 'custom'
bir_date = DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget(years=range(1910, 2020)), label="")
widgets = {
        'first_name_user': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First 
        'e_mail': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Your Email'}),
        'e_mail2': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Re-Entere Email'}),
        'password': widgets.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'New Password'}),
        'password2': widgets.PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Re-Entere Password'}),
        'bir_date': forms.DateField(),
        }
```

But in page widgets does not work, I see only empty fields without placeholders. 
Why?

Comment: The first line within the `widgets` variable is bad formed. Are you aware of that?

Comment: The first line within the widgets variable is bad formed - only in this cite. In originals is good:'first_name_user': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'First Name'}), - Bad copy